# Alternative for .Release.Time in Helm v3

Tags: kubernetes-helm, sprig-template-functions

Since Helm v3 built-in object `.Release.Time` [is removed](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/builtin_objects/#helm).

What is the preferred way of injecting a release time into a template now?

Comment: All I've found so far is this thread: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/5732

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like one of the [sprig date](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/date.html) functions is the way to go now.

For example:

```
metadata:
    annotations:
        timestamp: {{ now | quote }}
```

Comment: At least from the implementation standpoint, using now always returns a new value while the .Release.time might not (from a quick code read, it looks like its getting initalizied once).

Depending on what you do with 'now' it might not be the same as .Release.time