# helm 3 .Release.time.Seconds does not exist

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am now working in the migration from helm 2 to 3.

I am using the value of `.Release.time.Seconds` in my charts. I have seen that in helm 3 `.Release.time` does not exists. Trying to use `now` as it is explained in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61140638/alternative-for-release-time-in-helm-v3), I can do the instalation, but I do not get the expected value.

For example, with the following code:

```
 template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        dateInSeconds: "{{ .Release.Time.Seconds }}"
```

The label gets the value `dateInSeconds: 1611923156`

If I use the `now` function:

```
 template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        dateInSeconds: {{ now | quote }}
```

The label gets the value `dateInSeconds: "2021-02-01 12:05:28.6116854 +0100 CET m=+2.394553701"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the solution in [sprig](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/date.html). For getting the epoch time I can use `unixEpoch`.

So the solution is:

```
template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        dateInSeconds: {{ now | unixEpoch | quote}}
```

Comment: In case you need it working at the same time for helm 2 and 3, i used the following code:
`​dateInSeconds: {{ now | quote | trunc 28 | replace "\"" "" | replace ":" "-" |  replace " " "_" | quote}}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below instead.

```
{{ now | unixEpoch }}
```

Comment: I found that I needed `{{ now | unixEpoch | quote}}` to get it to work.